# Why was this closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

4 years ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106075/why-are-threads-so-expensive-that-event-driven-non-blocking-io-is-better-on-ben) about the differences between threaded and event loop style management of network client on SO.

Looking back at it, I'm not entirely sure why it was closed as off-topic, I was asking for something quite tangible and the answers that were written while the question was open helped me a lot understanding the difference.

I'm just wondering if someone could point me to why it was closed so I wouldn't ask another off-topic question.

Comment: What kind of question do you have in mind NOW? Maybe we can help you figure out if this one is on topic or not :).

Comment: @Patrice well, I'd still be wondering about this particular topic today hasn't I asked about it. Nothing in particular. But nevermind. I already [regret asking](http://i.imgur.com/cfRLTiN.png).

Comment: @Gant that is called the meta effect. That question you linked to is not at the quality standards of the site. Here, you just flashed a giant spotlight on it and pointed the more quality minded people around the site to it :/...

Comment: @Patrice that being said, it's still far more useful than today's run-of-the-mill well-asked debug-my-code question.

Comment: @JanDvorak oh for sure, not arguing that. I didn't downvote either as I don't think this is necessarily downvote worthy (+ I try to never downvote when it's the meta effect)

Comment: You violated the "ask, don't tell" policy :)  Your question pisses off any programmer that has been using httpd every day and never realized it was necessary to switch.  They are not looking forward to seeing *more* reasons they need to switch, they don't want to switch, so they'll look for any reason to close.  Never hard to find "rhetorical".  Just keep your question neutral without hi-lighting a specific product or tool.

Comment: Reopened and, presumably, with a couple new upvotes. Controversy!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question wasn't closed as off-topic. It was closed as **Not a real question**. That is a close reason that no [longer exist](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) but was [replaced (together with **not constructive**) with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154):

> - **unclear what you’re asking** — Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
>   As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're
>   asking.
> - **too broad** — There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to
>   narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a
>   few paragraphs.
> - **primarily opinion-based** — Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this
>   question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather
>   than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Even by today standards your question is broad but I'm not sure if I would spend a close vote on it today. That might be caused by the other low quality posts I see daily.

Here are the things that maybe, maybe, maybe make that question less broad:

- include the sources of your own research; *so we can check if your conclusion is right*
- be explicit: instead of *slows it down significantly* make sure to state the numbers: *on my setup apache can serve 1000 requests, Node 5000 requests per second.*
- Share how/what you monitored on/for both stacks

because that would be a good and narrow lead in to your question; *Now where is that striking, critical difference that makes threads so much worse?*

This might salvage this question but except that developers should have a common understanding of an event-loop versus a thread-based scheduling, it still misses a practical problem or issue that you want to have solved. In that sense your question ask us to explain concepts which is interesting but on Stack Overflow often considered too broad. Maybe an other SE site is open for this (but if you think [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) then please [think](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260) [twice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260))

Comment: Would this question fly on [programmers.se]?

Comment: I wouldn't dare to suggest it @JanDvorak but it was a site I had in mind when I wrote *maybe an other SE site is open for this* ...

Comment: @JanDvorak "where is that striking, critical difference" is hardly a good fit, see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260) (as usual, recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**)